# How do I prove the following: Let f be increasing and bounded below on (a,b) with largest lower bound l. Then f(x) tends to l as x tends to a+.

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

Currently working my way through some proofs for monotone functions and am struggling with the proof stated in the question. I have proved: Let $f$ be increasing and bounded above on $(a,b)$ with smallest upper bound $L$. Then $f(x) \rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow b-$. But I am struggling to prove the second case. Does I simply need to find an $x$ where $a<x<a + \delta$ that satisfies $|f(x)-l|< \epsilon$?

Comment: Given $\epsilon>0$ you have to find $\delta$ such that for  $b-\delta<x<b$ implies $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon$?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert Z. However I believe that is in the proof of $f$ increasing and bounded above on $(a,b)$ with smallest upper bound $L$, which I have already completed. I am wondering how to prove when $f$ is increasing and bounded below on $(a,b)$ with largest lower bound $l$. Or do I find a $\delta$ such that $b-\delta < x < b$ for both cases of the proof?

Answer (score 0):

You may reason as follows:

- As $f$ is monotone increasing and bounded from below, it exists $\lambda = \lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$
- Let $l$ be the greatest lower bound of $f$ on $(a,b) \Rightarrow l \leq f(x)$ on $(a,b) \Rightarrow l \leq \lambda$.
- Assuming $l < \lambda$ would result in $l' = \frac{l+\lambda}{2}$ being a lower bound for $f$ but greater than the greates one: $\Rightarrow$ Contradiction!

Comment: Is there a way to prove it regarding $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?

Comment: @J.Bry Why do you require any $\epsilon,\delta$ in your proof? Where exactly do you want to see it and why? What exactly do you want to prove and what exactly are you allowed to use as known?